# How to handle border image with transparent background and background image

Tags: border, background-image, transparent, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [css3 border-image's transparent png issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052295/css3-border-images-transparent-png-issue)

I have a border image with a transparent background and a width of 7px, which looks like this:

[image]

I have a repeating background image on the same div, which either overlaps the border-image, or which leaves a gap when I use the CSS:

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

There is also a background-image on the parent div, which is why I need a transparent background on the border image on the outside.

So I am wondering what options I have to make the repeating background image fit within the border image.  I could set the background position, but as I understand it, I can only set a starting position with x and y values, so this wouldn't work with the right and bottom position.

Perhaps then my only option is to fill the border image with the image that I am using for the background image in  Adobe Illustrator, but then I'd have to work out how to repeat a pattern on an artboard in Illustrator.  There may also be an issue with how the center section of the border image repeats on the page (i.e. will the background image look OK where the sections of the border image join?).

I'd be grateful for any advice on how best to achieve the result I am looking for.  You can see the border image in action on [this page](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/).  The main content and sidebar, and slide down contact form all have a background image which overlaps the border image.

**SCREENSHOT:**

[image]

Comment: I don't see an issue in Firefox or Chrome, only IE8. But IE8 does not support CSS3, hence `background-clip` is a no-go. Is this issue with IE8 only?

Comment: No, it's on all browsers.  I haven't got on to testing in IE yet - there's probably lot's that doesn't work there yet!! You have to zoom in to see that the background-image overlaps the border.  What I am seeing is what I would expect, i.e. that the background-image would stretch to the edges of the div, and would show through the border-image, if the border-image has a transparent background.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this error, as I don't see anything the matter or am not understanding the error correctly. I zoomed in too with no ill effects noted.

Comment: I see a white area extending beyond the border image. Are you trying to eliminate that?

Comment: Yes, this 'white' area is basically the repeating background image extending to the edges of the div (with a border-radius to round the corners), and which therefore shows behind the border-image.

Comment: I found this [**SO Question: css3 border-image's transparent png issue**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4052295/1195891) that may solve this similar, if not identical, problem.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll look into that.  I'm starting to think that filling the border-image in Illustrator may be the most straight forward solution, as I've had a go at it and it looks fine where the sections of the border-image join.